# MSAccess VBA: How do I detect when a sound occurs in the microphone over a decibel level?

Tags: audio, detection

How do I detect when a sound occurs in the microphone over a decibel level? I've got code for a timer that is triggered by user clicking buttons for start/stop. I'd like to use the microphone to detect sounds above a decibel level to trigger events and log the time they occur.

Comment: Welcom to SO, please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You have to record sound (getting values of the amplitude) and check which part of it is above your decibel. There are algorithms via web search to calculate decibel / sound pressure / etc.. The simplest would be to just read the amplitudes as the mic records....

Comment: It would be great to read amplitudes as the mic records. How do I do that in MS Access 2016? I've been able to use the MCISendString commands to record, capture, and write to a wav file. I can't find any help on reading the wav file to see when the sound occurred. Doing in real-time without needing to save a wav file would be better. How?